# How can I create a non-standard section in the backmatter?

Tags: fonts, sectioning, koma-script

I have a book that uses the `scrbook` class.

I need to add a chapter with a list of sources (pictures, where they have been taken from, which licence etc), which should be the last "chapter" in the backmatter after bibliography / index.

I created a new page with `\pagestyle{empty}` and wrote `{\usekomafont{chapter}List of Sources}`, but the heading is set in Computer Modern, not in the font, that is used in all the chapter headings.

Is there maybe a less manual and more straight-forward / KOMA-Script-compliant approach for creating an additional section like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If normal text should use the same font as chapter titles, you have to use `\usekomafont{disposition}\usekomafont{chapter}`. By the default element `disposition` uses `\normalcolor\sffamily\bfseries` and element `chapter` uses `\huge` (with option `headings=big`, default), `\LARGE` (with option headings=`normal`) or `\large` (with option `headings=small`).

Example:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\begin{document}
\chapter{First chapter}
Some Text.

\noindent{\usekomafont{disposition}\usekomafont{chapter}Some text with chapter font.\par}

\noindent Some Text.
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

But for special chapters I would use `\addchap{List of Sources}` (unnumbered but with entry in ToC and page header) or `\addchap*{List of Sources}` (unnumbered without entry in ToC and page header).

Example:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\addchap*{Special chapter}
\Blindtext
\addchap{Another special chapter}
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

It would be also possible to declare a new sectioning command using `\DeclareNewSectionCommand` if there additional special requirements.

Comment: A brief precise enlightening and comprehensive answer - thank you so much!